# Will my website be indexed as usual after hiding temporarily using htaccess and then bringing it live?

Tags: .htaccess, web

I would password-protect/hide the website using htaccess to disallow robots. Then If I bring it live after some weeks, will the indexing work as usual or should be notified using Google webmaster tools?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

robots crawl your page more than once so I think it will be reindexed after some weeks